# My function is being seemingly being skipped for no reason

Tags: c++

Attempting a basic C++ challenge, (beginner at C++) and I produced this code. I understand that calling a value in an array starts from zero but I wanted the user to type from 1-5 instead of 0-4 because I didn't want to go the easy route and wanted to see if I could do it.

Here is my problem, I made a basic function to subtract 1 from the int choice to allow the user to enter 1-5 but the array see the value as 1-4. However as shown in this image [image] it seems to ignore my function and skip to the next part of the code. I have included my code below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string drink[5] = { "Coke", "Water", "Sprite", "Monster", "Diet Coke" };

int choice;
int correct = 0;

void AdjArray()
{
    choice--;
};

int main()
{

    while (correct != 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of the beverage you would like." << endl;
        cout
                << " Coke      = 1\n Water     = 2\n Sprite        = 3\n Monster   = 4\n Diet Coke = 5"
                << endl;

        cin >> choice;

        AdjArray;

        if (choice >= 0 && choice <= 4)
        {
            cout << "You have chosen " << drink[choice] << "." << endl;
            correct = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Error, you entered: " << choice
                    << ". Please enter a number between 1 and 5.\n" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're calling AdjArray.  You need parens to call the function

Comment: So the computer is persecuting you?  No, it's always a mismatch between your assumptions and reality.  The code is wrong, and you put the bug there.  A spin in a debugger will show you the light.

Comment: As @GarrettR states, you call that function like this `AdjArray();`.

Comment: Check thine warning messages. They are like mana from the gods. `warning C4551: function call missing argument list`

Comment: I adjusted my code, the same results. I have also attempted without that function and replacing it with `choice--;` but also yields the same result.

Comment: Odd. I put the missing brackets in and get the expected results. "1 You have chosen Coke." "3 You have chosen Sprite."

Comment: One more thing to watch for is input of non-numbers. You want an `if` around `cin >> choice;` to catch that case and then an else to clean up the stream error state after the bad input so you can carry on reading.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling your function. Change `AdjArray;` to `AdjArray();`